# Apply filtering conditions from a file and parse it to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, filter, eval

Say we have data frame like this

```
import pandas as pd
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [' RACHEL  ', ' MONICA  ', ' PHOEBE  ',
                               '  ROSS    ', 'CHANDLER', ' JOEY    '],
                        
                      'Age val': [30, 35, 37, 33, 34, 30],
                        
                      'Salary val': [100000, 93000, 88000, 120000, 94000, 95000],
                        
                      'JOB': ['DESIGNER', 'CHEF', 'MASUS', 'PALENTOLOGY',
                              'IT', 'ARTIST']})
```

[image]

and have csv file that contains filtering conditions

[image]

I want to loop through csv file and put 'and' condition in between the 'Filter formula' row values. Concatenate and parse them to `pandasdataframe`.

```
   filters = ''
        
        for i, cols in csv_file.iterrows():
            
            formula = cols['Filter_Formula']
            filters = filters.join(formula + "&")
        print(filters)
```

when I print 'filters' I get

```
ASalary val<= 100000&gSalary val<= 100000&eSalary val<= 100000& Salary val<= 100000&vSalary val<= 100000&aSalary val<= 100000&lSalary val<= 100000& Salary val<= 100000&>Salary val<= 100000& Salary val<= 100000&3Salary val<= 100000&5Salary val<= 100000&&
```

but what I want to get is

```
    dataFrame= dataFrame[dataFrame.eval(filters)]
```

where `filters` are

```
    "Salary val <=100000 & (Age val > 35"
```

How I can we do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can construct a query expression by joining the strings in the `Filter_Formula` column around the delimiter `&`. Note: As the column name contain spaces, we need to quote the column names with backticks to construct  a valid query expression

```
df.query('&'.join(f.replace(n, f'`{n}`') for n, f in csv_file.to_numpy()))
```

---

```
      Name    Age val  Salary val    JOB
2   PHOEBE         37       88000  MASUS
```

Comment: Can you show how you get the 'filters' ? Because I'm having trouble with it too!

Comment: Check the edit, previously it was used as an alias for the `csv_file`. Now, I've removed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Did you mean csv_file['Filter_Formula']. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Alexander Assuming there are two columns in the `csv_file` we can simply use `csv_file.to_numpy()` inside a list comprehension to iterate over the column name and formula pairs.

Comment: @Shubnam Sharma What if we have more than two columns ? I'm getting error when I run the same code! Check the edit in OP!

Comment: @Alexander Check `df.query('&'.join(f.replace(n, f'`{n}`') for n, f in csv_file[['Column name', 'Filter_Formula']].to_numpy()))`